# Transparent text with css

Tags: css

[image: transparent text]

I need write any text in transparent ( instead of "200" ) like in image. Instead of " 200 " i need change this text. Is it possible???

HTML :

```
<div class="blocks">
      <div class="trans-200">200</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you are trying to do is not a transparent text. That is only possible with a png or gif.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do this cross-browser, unless you use an image.
There is a possibility for webkit though:

```
background: url(images/wood_texture.jpg) repeat;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
```

http://www.silenceit.ca/2011/03/11/css-gradients-and-webkit-image-masks-on-text/

Comment: I can't use image here coz i need change this text

Comment: @Umidjon Urunov as i told you in my Answer, there is only a solution for webkit. Not for the other browser for now.